# Different expressions for "ten" in Russian: десять, десятка, десяток

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова, падежи, числительные

In terms of expressing *ten*, what's the difference between **десять**, **десятка** and **десяток**? I understand the first is a numeral and the other two are nouns, but I'm curious to know in what contexts each is used.

Also, in the sentence **Он сыграл в кино десятки ролей**, is десятки a declined form of десятка or десяток?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Десятка** - Typically, an informal reference to something *numbered 10* (like a bus following route 10) or about a *10 ruble banknote* (in the past, when it mattered more). Now, it can sometimes informally mean 10,000 rubles; or informally refer to a 10-year prison sentence (ему дали "десятку").

**Десяток** - *10 pieces* (similar to *a dozen* eggs etc.), *10 years of age* in expressions like "ему уже седьмой *десяток*" (he's already in his 60's). It can also be used to approximate time (прошёл/пройдёт десяток лет - один или более десятков). Mathematically, *десятки* (plural)refers to the tens slot in numbers.

P.S. In *"Он сыграл в кино десятки ролей"*, **десятки** is the accusative plural form of десят**ок**.

Answer (score 8):

> Also, in the sentence **Он сыграл в кино десятки ролей**, is десятки a
> declension of десятка or десяток?

this is a declined `десяток`

`десятки` is never meant in a literal sense of quantity but just used to indicate a `great amount` within certain limits — in this case under 100.
In this usage, as Alex_ander noted, it's used idiomatically to refer to blocks of ten, Cf. `dozens`.

Likewise `cотни`, `тысячи`, `десятки тысяч` and so on.

At the same time, `десяток` and the nouns just listed can indicate a precise number if qualified by a numeral

> **Он сыграл в кино *два десятка* ролей**

or express uncertainty about the accuracy of the number (quantity) if followed by one (there's a more general syntactic rule at work here)

> **Он сыграл в кино *десятка два* ролей**

---

So, in an attempt to summarize this, it might be said that **десятка** (and any other numerical cognate noun ending in `-ка` such as *`тройка`*, *`семёрка`*, *`двадцатка`*, *`пятидесятка`* and so on) can be applied to something solid and indivisible, whereas **десяток** - to a set of separate items of one kind.

The difference can be seen in the following sentence:

> Я купил десяток (штук) десяток = Я купил десять (штук) десяток

where the 2nd `десятка` means `an item numbered 10`, for example a spool of sewing thread size 10, and so the entire sentence means `I bought ten items of the (number) 10`.

Answer (score 7):

ДЕСЯТКА (coll.) fem. noun:

1. The name of the number "ten"
2. Colloquially, the name of a means of transport (a bus, a tram) which  has the number 10

   > Какой автобус тут ходит? — Десятка.
3. Bull's-eye (sports) — the black circle in the center of a target, as in the idiom:

   > попасть в десятку — to hit the nail right on the head.
4. A ten-ruble coin
5. A card, e.g. the ten of spades — десятка пик, the ten of hearts — десятка червей.

---

ДЕСЯТОК masc. noun:

1. Ten things (Cf. *dozen*)

   > Десяток пирожных.
2. Decade (in age)

   > Ему пошёл шестой десяток — He's in his fifties.
3. A group of ten people

   > Десяток ребят.
4. In mathematics, the tens — тысячи, сотни, десятки, единицы.
5. A score of десятка два людей

---

Idioms

> Не робкого десятка — He's brave.

> Добрый десяток лет — Over a decade; a good ten years.