# десяток and its class of numeric forms

Tags: числительные

I could only find десяток and девяток. What is the range of numbers from 1 to 10 for this numeric form? Is десяток merely a declined form for десятка?

Answer (score 3):

The group nouns for animate sentient beings are as follows (governed by Plural Genitive and works with Neutrum and Masculine words only): ***двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро.*** Then there are more productive adverbial forms (like ***вдвоём, вшестером, всемером, ввосьмером,*** etc., but I guess they might be a little bit outside of the scope of your question).

For Feminine nouns, usual [Slavic Counting](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/special-treatment-for-plural-forms-depending-on-number-of-objects-where-does-i) is applied.

The group nouns for both animate (regardless on whether sentient or not) and inanimate objects are as follows: ***пара*** (***двойка*** is usually applied either as a word for a school mark or a suit type), ***тройка, четвёрка, пятёрка, шестёрка, семёрка, восьмёрка, девятка, десяток,*** there is no specific word for eleven objects, then come ***дюжина*** (12), ***двадцатка*** (20), ***тридцатка*** (30), then there is a gap for 40 followed by ***пол-сотни*** (50) and ***сотня*** (100).

Otherwise, standard compound nouns are applied (NB: the post-decimal numbers 2 and 1 should correlate in genders, e. g. ***сорок один год***, ***сорок одна лошадь***, ***сорок одно окно***).

Answer (score 2):

**Девяток** is a declined form (feminine *девятка* -> plural *девятки* -> genitive case *девяток*), while **десяток** has its own meaning (ten pieces of smth.) and just *coincides* in spelling with that form (*десятка* in plural + in genitive case).

In the meaning and form of *десяток*, there's **no** *range of numbers*, it is only possible to mention **пара** (inform. 2 pieces, две штуки), **пяток** (very informally, пять штук, 5 pieces you buy), **полдюжины** (obsolete, 6 штук) - that's all.

A related discussion:

[Express "ten" in Russian: difference between десять, десятка, десяток](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13196/express-ten-in-russian-difference-between-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: On what principle do you list only *полдюжины* but not *дюжины* or *полсотни*?

Comment: Strictly speaking пара may only be used with things that come in pairs, like boots etc. However, almost no-one respects this rule these days.

Comment: @J-mster Дюжина (as well as полсотни) is _out_ of the suggested range 1-10. The mentioned words can be used as **measure units** - same as _десяток_. This is different from the usage of _десятка_ and related words (единица, двойка... девятка) which just can be combined with some nouns to describe a **group** consisting of some number of people or things. But it's not the same: you can buy _десяток_ яиц, **not** _десятку_ or **семёрку**, etc. яиц.

Comment: @ AlexVB I agree, and that is why I originally added the _inform_. marking. Still, expressions like "пару дней", "пару раз", etc. are widely used colloquially.

Answer (score 1):

For groups of **animate objects of one kind/category** Russian employs the name of the corresponding digit

> **пятёрка** всадников
>   **тройка** друзей
>   великолепная **семёрка**

except for `единица` аnd `двойка` (because there's `пара`), and for a group of 10 beings `десяток` will rather be used instead of `десятка`

Although admittedly it is more of a literary form and has limited use confined to a set of familiar or tested cases. Not every such phrase will sound natural.

Answer (score 0):

Same appearance, not always same meaning. Such forms and similar number designations have often special uses.

1. Единица — mostly as *oldisch* worst school grade, from "1", obviously. Also: a unit. *Боевая единица* – a military unit.
2. Двойка - again, the worst currently used school grade. *Can* be used as "pair of something", but there is also `пара`, as mentioned above.
3. Тройка - triplet. Mostly the three horses in a row in the same carriage. I bet, you have seen the pictures. *Эх тройка, птица-тройка, куда же ты так несешься?*
4. Четверка - quadruple.
5. Пятерка. Both 4 and 5 can be perceived as school grades that go up to 5. I think, there is a chain of markets called "Пятерочка", a dimutive. I perceive simply `пятерка` depending on context either as best grade or a group of five. Also a money bill of 5.
6. Шестерка. Has a derogatory meaning of a smallish criminal helper from the criminal argo, wide spread in the 90s and somewhat established in the informal conversational language. Before that, aside from, "a group of six", the 210**6** model of Lada. Mentioned above: oldisch spoken language: `полдюжины`, that's of quantity only.
7. Семерка. A group of seven, the number seven, I recall no extra meanings. there was a cheap alcoholic brewage in Soviet time called 777, so `три семерки`.
8. Восьмерка. Dito.
9. Девятка. Dito, maybe also the 9 at a shooting exercise.
10. Десятка. Dito, also with shooting. Also a money bill of value 10.

I know spontanously no such construct with 11. 12 is `дюжина`, there is also 13 — `чертова дюжина`, although more conversational. 20 with `двадцатка` and 50 with `пятидесятка` is for me purely a money bill designations, and not those of a written language.

- 50 — пятьдесят, but also `полста`, esp. in military radio exchange.
- 100 — стольник (money), also `сотка` – rather in designations, but also for money: *А потом сотки подтянулись, так мы и выжили.* (on appearance of СУ-100 on the battlefield); *— Почем пластинка Битлов? / — Сотка!* (from bootleg music trade in 60s-70s); сто грамм, стопка — a vodka dosage.
- 500 — пятьсот, but also полтысячи.
- 1000 — тысяча, *very old, not in modern language:* тьма, *modern jargon:* штука, esp. of money, somewhat oldisch jargon, unsure: `кусок`.
- 1 000 000 — миллион, *jargon:* лимон
- 1 000 000 000 — миллиард, *jargon:* лярд.